# Upper limit of Schumann resonance harmonics?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, geophysics, harmonics

<sub>This is a re-post from the [Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/22809) which was posted two month ago. Due to the nature of the question and the SE site, it might be better to post this question here.</sub>

---

As the Earth's surface-ionospheric gap acts as a resonator for electromagnetic waves, it should have several harmonic values from the base, fundamental frequency of 7.83 Hz. ([Schumann resonances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schumann_resonances)) These are integer multiples, but there is a limit as to how high the frequency can go for it to have an effect, especially so for the Schumann resonance, as the gap between the lithosphere and ionosphere can change due to events in space, mainly the sun. Hence, what is the maximum range of integer frequency values for the Schumann resonance?

---

[image: Schumann resonance] [source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Schumann_resonance_01_en.png)

Comment: Do you have a reference to how the gap between the lithosphere and ionosphere affects the resonaces?